# How to serve internal ip camera mjpeg stream through servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, java-me, video-streaming

I'm working on a project where I have a simple ip camera that has an mjpg stream with an internal address and a web server. I would like to serve the camera's feed through my servlet so that the camera does not require port forwarding for each installation. My ideal situation would be that the user would only enter the URL for the mjpg's location (located on their network) and the servlet would handle the rest.

I'm pretty clueless on how to begin implementing this or if it's even possible as I'm not actually creating the mjpg stream myself, I'm using the one that already exists. Is there a way to do this without making an obscene amount of requests to my web server?

An additional thorn in my side is that I'm restricted to libraries that would work in J2ME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a servlet, you can simply inspect the HttpRequestObject for the URL, method, and probably accept header, then create an HttpURLConnection with the ip address of the appropriate camera, make the connection. When you get a response back from the camera, copy the appropriate entries from the response and set them in the ServletResponse object, and then get the camera response input stream and the output stream for the client's request and copy the bytes from one stream to another, and close everything up when you're done.

If you can deploy something like Jersey, the JAX-RS reference implementation, this would be even easier.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So you basically want to proxy several cameras to be connected to via a single servlet?

It shouldn't be too hard. You just need to open up a socket connection to the requested URL in your servlet.

Assuming you're using HTTP, if you had a request for "http://myservlet/servlet?url=http://camera_url_here", you should just be able to open up a connection to the camera URL and write the bytes received to the HttpServletResponse's Outputstream. You might want to stick your socket connections in a Map, so that you don't needlessly connect to the same camera twice. Don't forget to copy/set the correct MIME types in the HttpServletResponse object.

Have you looked at http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html ? I'm pretty sure it can already do this.